# Server answering client request threw pipes and tubes C

Tags: c, fork, named-pipes

- Short version :

I'm trying threw a request send by a client, awsering him back the result of the expression he wanted me to find.

- Longer version :

For this, I am firstly using mkfifo to create two named tubes : one for the server and one for the client. The client will connect himself to server's named tube and write the request. The server will read and in using a fork will determinate the resultat of message->expression (threw bc). After this, he will connect himself to client's named tube (tube's name = pid of the client) and send back the result. Finally the client printf it.

I have already asked how does work fork and bc, with all the redirection we should use. This does work when I'm not using mkfifo in the program (and create the named tube of the server and client before). I think I misunderstanding the correct use of open and mkfifo. I've tried to catch as much as possible errors, but that doesn't help me more.

Here the code : -SERVER-

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 20

typedef struct requete_client_serveur {
    pid_t client_pid;               //PID's clients
    char expression[BUFFER_SIZE-1]; //expression
}requete_client_serveur;

int main(){

    char resultat[5];
    int t1;
    int mk;


    //create server's named pipe
    char *fifoServeur = "serveurfifo";
    printf("%s\n", fifoServeur);

    if((mk = mkfifo(fifoServeur, 0777)) == -1 ){
        fprintf(stderr, "mkfifo's server failed \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Hello\n");

    //open server's named pipe
    if ((t1 = open(fifoServeur, O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "open server's named pipe failed \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    //While there are clients
    while(1){

        //For read the client's request
        requete_client_serveur* rcs = malloc(sizeof(requete_client_serveur));
        requete_client_serveur* message = (requete_client_serveur*) rcs;

        //Read the expression
        int nbytes = read(t1, rcs, sizeof(*rcs));
        if (nbytes <= 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "read from child failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


        printf("expression the client %d send : %s\n",getpid(),message->expression);


        //creation two tubes
        int pipe1[2];
        int pipe2[2];
        pipe(pipe1);
        pipe(pipe2);

        //fork
        int resultat_fork = fork();
        if (resultat_fork == -1)
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);


        if(resultat_fork!=0){ 
            printf("I am the parent\n");

            close(pipe1[0]);
            close(pipe2[1]);
            /* We don't need pipe1's input and pipe2's output */

            if (write(pipe1[1],message->expression, strlen(message->expression)) != strlen(message->expression))
                fprintf(stderr, "write to child failed\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

            //open client's tube
            int t2;
            char fifoClient[10];

            sprintf(fifoClient,"%u", message->client_pid);

            printf("%s\n", fifoClient);

            if ((t2 = open(fifoClient, O_WRONLY)) == -1){
                fprintf(stderr, "open client's named pipe failed \n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }


            /* Write the answer into the client's tube (here t2) */
            if(write(t2, resultat, sizeof(resultat)) != sizeof(resultat))
                    fprintf(stderr, "write to client (t2) failed\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);



            close(pipe1[1]);
            close(pipe2[0]);
            /* We don't need them anymore */



        }else{
            printf("I am the children\n");

            close(pipe1[1]);
            close(pipe2[0]);
            /* We don't need pipe1's output and pipe2's input */

            dup2(pipe1[0], 0);  
            dup2(pipe2[1], 1);
            /* Redirection input & output */

            close(pipe1[0]);
            close(pipe2[1]);
            /* More closes */

            execlp("bc", "bc", NULL);
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute bc\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
}
```

CLIENT :

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


#define BUFFER_SIZE 20

typedef struct requete_client_serveur {
    pid_t client_pid;               //PID's clients
    char expression[BUFFER_SIZE-1]; //expression
}requete_client_serveur;

int main(){

    int t1,t2;
    char resultat[5];

    //open serveur's named tube
    char *fifoServeur = "serveurfifo";

    if((t1 = open(fifoServeur, O_WRONLY)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "open server's named pipe failed \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //create client's named tube using his pid as descriptor
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    char fifoClient[10];
    int mk;

    sprintf(fifoClient,"%u", pid);
    printf("%s\n", fifoClient);
    if((mk = mkfifo(fifoClient, 0777)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "open client's named pipe failed \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("%d\n",mk);  

    printf("cc\n");

    //Open it as a reader
    if ((t2 = open(fifoClient, O_RDONLY)) == -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "open client's named pipe failed \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("cc\n");

    //preparation request
    void* bc = malloc(sizeof(requete_client_serveur));
    requete_client_serveur* rcs = (requete_client_serveur*) bc;


    //expression we want to compute
    char *expression = "5*5\n";

    rcs->client_pid = pid;
    strcpy(rcs->expression, (char *)expression);


    //write the request to the server
    if (write(t1, rcs, sizeof(rcs)) != sizeof(rcs))
        fprintf(stderr, "write to server from client (t1) failed\n");


    //read the answer
    int nbytes = read(t2, resultat, sizeof(resultat));
    if (nbytes <= 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "read result failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    //printf it
    printf("resultat: %s\n", resultat);
}
```

When starting the two process, I keep having nothing from the server and the client (no error or sometimes if I'm lucky). If you have any idea to help me work that system, I would be very grateful. I don't necessary need the answer, I really want to understand how does that work.
Thank you for reading (please forgive my grammatical mistakes, english isn't my main language).

Comment: You forget to check if `mkfifo` fails. And you should not open with the `O_CREAT` flag.

Comment: And a probable culprit of your problem (I *think*, since it's not very clear what your problem actually *is*): `read(t1, rcs, sizeof(rcs))`. You only read the size of the *pointer*, not the size of the structure. Use `sizeof *rcs` instead.

Comment: Oh yes I forgot to check mkfifo. I am sorry if I haven't said it clairly, but the main problem here, is about mkfifo which don't want to work. On both sides I can't write and read threw the two named pipes. After cheking if mkfifo fails, it does indeed. But I don't understand why, isn't that way you use mkfifo ? [edit : i've uploaded the code]

Comment: In each but the first run of the server the `mkfifo(fifoServeur, 0777)` fails because the FIFO _file exists_ already.